# Import a java project in Eclipse Kepler without .project file

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I cloned a Java project to my local repo. When importing the project to Eclipse it gives me an error saying that No projects are found to import. 
Am using a Mac and the Eclipse package I am using is Kepler 64bit version.

Comment: If you don't have the .project, you don't have an Eclipse project. You just have sources. Nothing prevents you from recreating the project though.

Comment: It sounds like your `clone` may have left out the files starting with `.` try and get the clone to include these.

Comment: How is this project built? Maven and Gradle both provide support to generate an eclipse project (if configured to do so).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to import old project.
Try..
Create new project, copy source files to new project, use .classpath file of old project to add required jars as you would be working on different machine else copy same .classpth file

e.g. for classpath entry `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/libs/junit/junit-4.11.jar"/>` add *junit-4.11.jar* to the build path